# Loading Posts & Category with Ajax

Tags: php, posts, categories, ajax

Is there any way to make this function also output another html template with the current selected category's data?

```
function load_cat_posts () {
$cat_id = absint($_REQUEST['cat']);
$args = array (
  'cat' => $cat_id,
  'posts_per_page' => 10,
  'order' => 'DESC'
);

global $post;
$posts = get_posts($args);

ob_start ();

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
  setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

<?php get_template_part( 'partials/listing', 'post'); ?>

<?php } wp_reset_postdata();

$response = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo $response;
die(
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, the [`get_template_part()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) function can be called multiple times referencing to different files, so if you have a file in the `partials/`-folder, all you have to do is add a second function call here.

```
function load_cat_posts () {
    $cat_id = absint($_REQUEST['cat']);
    $args = array (
       'cat' => $cat_id,
       'posts_per_page' => 10,
       'order' => 'DESC'
   );

    global $post;
    $posts = get_posts($args);

    ob_start ();

    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'partials/listing', 'post'); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'partials/listing', 'category'); ?>

    <?php } wp_reset_postdata();

    $response = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    echo $response;
    die(
}
```

This will include the file `partials/listing-category.php`.

*Edit: I misunderstood your question!* To display the data related to the category itself, you can use the `get_category` function to fetch an object containing the following attributes:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [term_id] => 85
    [name] => Category Name
    [slug] => category-name
    [term_group] => 0
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 85
    [taxonomy] => category
    [description] => 
    [parent] => 70
    [count] => 0
    [cat_ID] => 85
    [category_count] => 0
    [category_description] => 
    [cat_name] => Category Name
    [category_nicename] => category-name
    [category_parent] => 70
)
```

How you want to display this data is, of course, up to you.

```
function load_cat_posts () {
    $cat_id = absint($_REQUEST['cat']);
    $args = array (
       'cat' => $cat_id,
       'posts_per_page' => 10,
       'order' => 'DESC'
   );

   $category = get_category($cat_id);
   // ...
}
```

Comment: But would'nt that be within the foreach? I only want a single category picked out.

Comment: Hey, I think I misunderstood, see the updated answer.